# How do I setup a SMTP ID to my server?

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, dkim, spf

I am trying to increase email deliverability, from what I read, most important things I need to have set are SPF records, DKIM and sender ID, I set SPF and DKIM, but...

- "sender ID" is same as "SMTP ID" from email header?
- how do I setup a sender ID ?

// using Cent OS on my servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sender ID is the next generation SPF that hasn't happened yet. Basically nobody supports it and I feel confident in saying you'd be wasting your time. SPF is widely supported. DKIM is supported by most of the big guys, and any smaller ones that are serious about spam.

If you really want to setup Sender ID, it's just a series of SPF-like DNS records. The contents of the record are identical to SPF except the beginning, because the (possible multiple) SenderID record applies to different aspects of the e-mail depending on the contents of the record.

By example, if the record starts with:

`spf2.0/mfrom`, such as `spf2.0/mfrom mx -all` then the "mx -all" part applies to the "From" header.

`spf2.0/pra`, such as `spf2.0/pra mx -all` then it applies to the MAIL FROM: protocol negotiation.

You may also use both, such as `spf2.0/mfrom,pra mx -all`. 
Servers that support this *should* interpret it the same as "v=spf1 mx -all".